# Bangalore to Tiruvannamalai : Even, asphalt road

Tags: india, driving, road-trips, tamil-nadu

I am planning a drive (hatchback) from Bangalore to Tiruvannamalai in the first week of coming month

I understand that there are alternative routes available (listed) but have been in a state of repair in stretches. While it may be early for monsoon, rains would make the drive a nightmare on gravel roads since it would render the pot holes invisible filled with water

I have searched reputed sites like [Trip Advisor](https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowTopic-g2546088-i18246-k6754249-Better_route_from_Bangalore_to_Tiruvannamalai-Tiruvannamalai_Tamil_Nadu.html), [Holiday IQ](http://www.holidayiq.com/How-To-Reach/From-Bangalore-To-Tiruvannamalai-293-1149), [Team-BHP](http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/route-travel-queries/31032-bangalore-thiruvannamalai-route-queries-12.html) for help but the information is outdated and may not reflect reality. I even came across a [complaint](http://www.consumercomplaints.in/complaints/nh66-condition-terrible-krishnagiri-tiruvannamalai-krishnagiri-tamil-nadu-c473588.html) dated May this year about the dangerous condition of a national highway stretch

**Which is the route that offers even surface, least pot holes,  asphalt rather than gravel and wide enough for a hatchback? Distance, amenities are not a constraint**. The impression I gather is the last route on list is preferred with the given constraints. any better alternative would be appreciated

- Bangalore → Hosur → Kathujuganapalli → Uthangarai →Tiruvannamalai.
- Bangalore → Krishnagiri → Bargur → Tirupattur →Singarapettai → Tiruvannamalai.
- Bangalore → Krishnagiri → Karimangalam → Kambinallur → Morappur → Harur → Theerthamalai → Andiyur →Thanipadi → Radha Puram →Tiruvannamalai

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I said in chat, I have been living in Tiruvannamalai for the last four years and have traveled to Bangalore by road several times. However, I haven't done it since 2013. Back then, the road was absolutely horrible, because there was a lot of construction going on. However, it seems to have gotten much better now.

To get some up-to-date information on matters, I called local friend of mine who is a professional driver and owns a company that provides long-distance taxis. He knew you'd be driving your own car, so he had no financial interest in the matter.

#### Going through Krishnagiri

He recommends that you drive straight from Bangalore to Krishnagiri, then straight from Krishnagiri to Tiruvannamalai. This also involves going through some of the smaller towns you mentioned.

[image]

While this route was absolutely terrible a few years ago, my friend says it has gotten much better now. Overall, he reccomends this route. From Bangalore to Hosur there is a quality multiple-lane highway. For the rest of the distance, the majority of the construction work is now done. My friend says 70% of the distance is now completely finished and has a quality road, fulfilling the criteria which you specify. However, 30% of the distance is apparantly still of questionable quality. For example, there are some places where there is still construction going on. On those stretches, there will be temporary gravel roads on the side of the road, and these are of poor quality. Among thee 30% "poor part" there are also still stretches with potholes, bumps and general low quality.

To summarize, the road is a lot better than it was, but still not perfect. Yet, my friend says it's the best option.

**Update:** One of my friends took this route the other day. He said it's 90% good now. But he discourages using it at night.

#### Going through Tirupattur

[image]

If you want to avoid the construction work altogether, you could go through Tirupattur. However, this is a much smaller and narrower road. It's much more rural. It has a lot of bends and turns. According to my friend, your average speed will be reduced by roughly half if you take this route. The overall distance will  also be longer.

It seems like those are your two main options, so take your pick.

<sup>Images: Google Maps, fair use.</sup>

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot and deeply appreciate the local knowledge which can't be found on net :)

Comment: Stumbled on this [very recent post](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-road-condition-now-from-Bangalore-to-Tiruvannamalai) which suggests that the second route is better and was anyway my choice too. Adding it for the benefit of future visitors

Answer (score 2):

On 2 Sept 2017, I travelled from Krishnagiri to T-Vanamalai by car, going through the S.Pettai regular route. It has improved, but the roads are still about 20 percent under repair.

Answer (score 0):

After the Krishnagiri toll gate, you might be better taking the service road bearing toward the left to get onto the T-Malai road, instead of taking the bridge; be careful, as it is confusing there.

Comment: I have edited your response, hoping to make it a bit clearer; if I have misunderstood, apologies. You can undo the changes, or add to it, if you wish.